# getAccessTokenAsync returns 13001 only on safari

Tags: safari, office-js

I'm using OWA in safari and when I call getAccessTokenAsync it return 13001, but it works fine on chrome

Windows (ie, edge, chrome) works fine
MAC (chrome) works fine

MAC (safari) return 13001
I have try to pass { forceAddAccount:true }

```
Office.onReady().then(function (value) {
   Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync({ forceConsent: false }, function (result) {
      console.log('Checking token: ' + result.status);
   });
});
```

Expected result: status:'succeeded'
Actual result: 13001 the user is not signed in Office

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if you have 3rd party cookies enabled or disabled on Safari. If disabled, can you follow the instructions given here to enable 3rd party cookies:
https://www.clubrunnersupport.com/article/710-enable-third-party-cookies-for-safari